# what are the Major Parameter changes in postgresql 13 to postgresql 15?

Tags: postgresql-15

What are all major parameters changes from Postgresql13 to Postgresql15,have gone through the new features but our system all are version13 and now we need to know about postgresql w.r.t Parameter changes,extenstions etc..

Comment: please adjust titel to postgresql 15 (not 5)

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/14.0/

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/15.0/

Answer (score 0):

For us the big gotcha was this:

> Change the default of the password_encryption server parameter to scram-sha-256 (Peter Eisentraut)
>
> Previously it was md5. All new passwords will be stored as SHA256 unless this server setting is changed or the password is specified in MD5 format. Also, the legacy (and undocumented) Boolean-like values which were previously synonyms for md5 are no longer accepted.

In our case we needed to update our JDBC driver for compatibility.

Otherwise go through the compatibility section of the release notes, as has been suggested in the comments:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/14.0/
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/15.0/